# MATLAB function input argument

Tags: matlab, function

I am facing problem in passing a vector to a matlab function defined in m file.someone told me that only single value variables can be passed as arguments to a function, not vector/array/matrix? Is it true ? If true then matlab is of no use? please help me...

thanking you

Comment: are you getting an error message when you try to pass a vector to the .m file? please give the details. in general (almost) all of MATLAB's builtin functions where it would make sense to pass a vector or matrix accept them.

Comment: A code snippet as well as the exact error message would be of great use to help us diagnose what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely not true. You can pass vectors and matrices to functions defined in m files in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You probably confuse with C or something.